# Rails - Liking Comments Made on Posts - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my application, I have `Users`, who can Create `Project` Postings. On each Project Posting, they can make comments that I have made a `Blogupdate` model.  I want users to be able to like Blogupdates made on each Project page.

So, I created a Bloglike model.  But when I try to render a LIKE/UNLIKE button, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Projects#blogs
undefined method `bloglikes_path'
Extracted source (around line #11):
11:     <%= form_for(current_user.bloglikes.build(blogupdate_id: blogupdate.id)) do |f| %>
```

**Question: As a note, I have not built up the controller for the actual create/destroy function in my bloglikes controller; but looking at my attached code below, does somebody know how I can resolve this error so the like/unfollow button renders?**

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "bloglikes", :force => true do |t|
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.integer  "blogupdate_id"
   t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
   t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
end

add_index "bloglikes", ["blogupdate_id"], :name => "index_bloglikes_on_blogupdate_id"
add_index "bloglikes", ["user_id", "blogupdate_id"], :name => "index_bloglikes_on_user_id_and_blogupdate_id", :unique => true
add_index "bloglikes", ["user_id"], :name => "index_bloglikes_on_user_id"
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :bloglikes, foreign_key: "user_id"
has_many :liked_blogupdates, through: :bloglikes, source: :blogupdate
```

**blogupdate.rb**

```
has_many :bloglikes, foreign_key: "blogupdate_id"
has_many :liked_by, through: :bloglikes, source: :user

def liking_blogupdate?(blogupdate)
   bloglikes.find_by_blogupdate_id(blogupdate.id)
end

def like_blogupdate!(blogupdate)
   bloglikes.create!(blogupdate_id: blogupdate.id)
end

def blogupdate_unlike!(blogupdate)
   bloglikes.find_by_blogupdate_id(blogupdate.id).destroy
end
```

**bloglike.rb**

```
class Bloglike < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :blogupdate_id

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :blogupdate, foreign_key: "blogupdate_id"
end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def blogs
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @blogupdates = @project.blogupdates.newest.page(params[:blogupdates_page]).per_page(5)
end
```

**views/projects/blogs.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'blogs' %>
```

**views/projects/_blogs.html.erb**

```
<%= render @blogupdates %>
```

**views/blogupdates/_blogupdates.html.erb**

```
<%= blogupdate.liked_by.count %>
<% if current_user.liking_blogupdate?(blogupdate) %>
  <%= form_for(current_user.bloglikes.find_by_blogupdate_id(blogupdate),
               html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "UNLIKE", class: "btn btn-medium" %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(current_user.bloglikes.build(blogupdate_id: blogupdate.id)) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field :blogupdate_id %></div>
      <%= f.submit "LIKE", class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

<p><%= raw blogupdate.content %></p>
```

**UPDATE: As noted below by @Dan, I forgot to update the routes.rb file. I added "resources :bloglikes" and it worked now.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post your `routes.rb` file but I'd wager that is where the problem is at. An undefined method related to routes (e.g. `bloglikes_path`) typically indicates you've not defined the routes.

Add `resources :bloglikes` to your project's `routes.rb` file and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks, resolved it! I updated my question to show what I did.